# 30 capacitors in parallell?

Tags: capacitor, filter

I can't find any uF valued capacitor with a high Q-rating (~150) for my required frequency  (~100 MHz). I need a 3 uF capacitor of this kind to realize my filter.

I have found a good capacitor that satisfies my specifications, but it has a value of 100 nF.

In theory, placing 30 of these would do the trick. How about in real life?

Comment: You're sure you can't scale the other components so that you don't need such a high capacitor value?

Comment: Your numbers seem completely improbable.  It might be worth going back and re-doing the calculations.  If you aren't sure, post your calculations here for the rest of us to look at.

Comment: I think it will work. Basically Q-factor is related with ESR and ESL. So do some math to check if parallel them will derate their Q-factor.

Comment: What is the application? It would be EXTREMELY unusual to require 3 uF at 100 MHz in a resonant circuit - not impossible, just suggests a very special application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what Q you are trying to achieve, but the capacitive reactance of 3uF at 100 MHz is in the 500\$\mu \Omega \$ range - it's going to be quite difficult to connect parts in a non-superconducting circuit and get the resistance very low in comparison- maybe with thick copper bus-bars. That's probably why you can't easily find commercial parts with that specification. Also capacitors with high pulse discharge capabilities may be export-controlled.

Comment: export controlled? I never heard about that, care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @PlasmaHH High discharge spec caps may be useful in triggers for nuclear bombs or high energy LASERS among other unlikely things. People tend to ask questions first and then ??? i n such area. ITAR regs prevent all sorts of unlikely things being exported.

Comment: F@PlasmaHH I think the concern is miniaturized nuclear triggers used in missiles, from the reason codes in 3A001.e.2. A 3uF cap would have to be rated at something like 8.5kV to 'trigger' the restrictions and would also have to be less than a certain mass (in the kg range). They're not parts you're going to need for normal electronics work.